# Set combo box value using VBA

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, database-design, combobox

I am attempting to set the value of a combo box from a "Splash Screen" type form in Access that will take the user's computer name and load two combo boxes on another form with the Employee ID and Manager ID, which are both bound columns of the combo boxes, which are unbound themselves. I can get the IDs in the combo box, but i want it to still display column 2 (Names) of both combo boxes. Right now it just displays the IDs. Anyone got any ideas how i can get it to react like i actually picked it in the combo box?

Comment: You should consider adding the code you have so far

Answer (score 0):

So, comboboxes can sometimes be tricky, but once you get it down you should be good to go.

So, when looking at a Combobox's properties,
The `Format` tab :

```
ColumnCount: 2       <-- You want the ID and the Name
ColumnWidths: 0";1"   <--- You're hiding the ID field, which is the first column
```

The `data` tab:
This is where you're going to tell Access what data you're supplying for your combobox.

Usually it's a query or table data source. If it's a query you should be selecting the `ID` and `Name` fields, and use that query in the `RowSource` property in the `Data` tab.

```
Row Source: Select ID, Name FROM YourTable
Row Source Type: Table/Query
```

When you use the Wizard to create the combobox, it's fairly straightforward. When Access asks you to format your data source, you completely shrink the `ID` column, so it hides it (but it's still there).

The steps would be:

1. I want the combobox to look up the values in a table or query
2. Select the Table or Query
3. Select the Fields (ID and Name seem appropriate for your scenario)
4. Any sorting you may want
5. The next screen is where we want to hide our `ID` column, so shrink it entirely
6. The next screen is where we tell Access that we want the `ID` to be in scope (selected) when we select a combobox item
7. Name it & be proud